# Renaming csv file with a variable name and moving to destination folder

Tags: python, csv, file, rename, python-datetime

I have a csv file in downloads folder with a name `export.csv`.
I need to rename the file in the format "REMSIMPORT + today's date" and move to destination folder.
For e.g. today's date is 2022-01-24. So `export.csv` will be renamed as `REMSIMPORT20220124`.
Tomorrow it will be `REMSIMPORT20220125`.
So it will change every time as per current date

This is how far I have reached.

```
from datetime import date

src_path = r'C:/Users/abc/Downloads/'
dest_path = r"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Weekly"

today_date = date.today()  # Extracted today's date
today_date = str(today_date).replace("-","")
```

I am confused on how to rename file with a variable `newname` (e.g. `REMSIMPORT20220124`) and moving to destination folder.

Comment: You need create a string with the name you want to assign. Add a print() commmand to check that the name is like you want. Then you have https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html where you have methods to create folders or rename files

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rename` method from `os` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename).

```
import os

src_path = r'C:/Users/abc/Downloads/' + 'REMSIMPORT'
dest_path = r'C:/Users/abc/Desktop/Weekly/' + 'REMSIMPORT' + today_date
os.rename(src_path, dest_path)
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a great alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `schedule` for your purpose.

```
$ pip install schedule
```

Here is some examples of `schedule` from the [page](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) :

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every(5).to(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

On your purpose, you can try something like this :

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import schedule
import time

def save_csv():
    today_date = str(date.today()).replace("-","")
    src_path = r'C:/Users/abc/Downloads/'
    dest_path = r'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Weekly'
    df = pd.read_csv(src_path + 'export.csv')
    df.to_csv(dest_path + 'REMSIMPORT' + today_date + '.csv')

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(save_csv)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: That `schedule` module is really helpful

Comment: Thank you. Scheduling is a great idea. It will enhance the script. I will add it

Answer (score 0):

Shutil copyfile should be good!

````
from datetime import date
from shutil import copyfile

src_path = r'C:/Users/user/adifferentdir'
dest_path = r"C:/Users/user/dir"

today_date = date.today()  # Extracted today's date
today_date = str(today_date).replace("-","")

copyfile(src_path+"/export.csv",dest_path+"/REMSIMPORT"+today_date+".csv")#copying file with new name```
````

Comment: Thank you! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the [`shutil.move()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) utility function would be the best option because not only can it move files, it can rename them at the same time. I've also found that using the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module makes file and directory path manipulations not only extremely easy but at very intuitive (and allow doing so in an OS portable way).

Anyway, here's an example of putting them to use to accomplish what you want to do.

```
from datetime import date
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import move

filename = 'export.csv'
#src_dir = Path('C:/Users/abc/Downloads/')
#dst_dir = Path('C:/Users/abc/Desktop/Weekly')

# Directories for testing.
src_dir = Path('./').resolve()
dst_dir = Path('./Weekly').resolve()

prefix = 'REMSIMPORT'
today_date = date.today()  # Extracted today's date
today_date = str(today_date).replace('-', '')
newname = prefix + today_date

if not dst_dir.exists():
    dst_dir.mkdir()  # Create destination directory since it doesn't exist.

src_path = src_dir / filename
dst_path = dst_dir / (newname + src_path.suffix)
move(src_path, dst_path)

print('fini')
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked as well.